# What is a good returnURL

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to find an example of a good "returnURL" to be used with the Microsoft-Graph-UWP-Connect-SDK example in github.

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <!-- Add your client id here. -->
    <x:String x:Key="ida:ClientID">xxxxx</x:String>
    <x:String x:Key="ida:ReturnUrl">???????</x:String>
</Application.Resources>
```

I've tried using the Application Registration Portal, but I cannot find the correct entry or results.

Answer (score 1):

*Return URIs* are the addresses that are allowed to be redirected on to pass the token/codes after authentication. From [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/laurelle/2016/02/12/how-to-use-microsoft-graph-and-office-365-api-in-a-service-or-in-a-windows-appuwp-without-a-graphical-interface/) example, I’ll use a Raspberry in a UWP. The name will be “laurellerpitest” and will return to port 81 on page *token*. So `http://laurellerpitest:81/token`

Important: Do give a read to [Getting the access token](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/laurelle/2016/02/12/how-to-use-microsoft-graph-and-office-365-api-in-a-service-or-in-a-windows-appuwp-without-a-graphical-interface/) on the same page.

And see if this works,

```
<Application.Resources>
        <!-- Add your client id here. -->
        <x:String x:Key="ida:ClientID">ENTER_YOUR_CLIENT_ID</x:String>
        <x:String x:Key="ida:ReturnUrl">`http://laurellerpitest:81/token</x:String>
    </Application.Resources>
```

Comment: I added the suggested ReturnUrl and get the following error msg Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalServiceException occurred
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=The provided value for the input parameter 'redirect_uri' is not valid. The client application must be marked as 'mobile', or the value must be an absolute URL which matches the registered redirect URI.
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>    I get this error when executing the following code:  if (await SignInCurrentUserAsync())

Comment: Sorry for that lame answer and inconvenience caused! I hope this helps @TreyBalut.